# Create a code that reads the content of file till particular string in the content using conditional statements

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have this code snippet which reads the file contents up to a particular string, and then copy the text file content to another file

I tried reversing the contents with an array,split method but I'm not getting the desired output.

```
$x = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Desktop\abc*.txt"
[array]::Reverse($x)

$d = foreach($line in $x)
{
    if($line - like "HEllo")

    {
        #Read the text file till "hello" and copy the contents
    }
}
```

Comment: so ... what do you want it to do? [*grin*] what is not working as expected?

Comment: Please edit the question and add an example input, what you'd like to get and what you actually get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to reverse the array with the content or use loops.

**Here is a simple solution:**

```
$x = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Desktop\abc*.txt" -Raw;

$pos = $x.IndexOf("Hello"); #position of the substring

$result = $x.Substring(0, $pos); #cuting the left part (before the substring)

$result | Out-File "C:\Users\Desktop\abc_out.txt"; #Output the result to file
```

**Explanation:**

1. Get the content of your file as **raw** string.
2. Find the position of the substring "Hello"
3. Cut the part before the substring
4. Output the result into file